# Is the bartender from The Punisher Season 2 a real character from marvel comics?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-punisher-tv

I don't have enough information about this, but I'd like to think that all Marvel movies/series are directly related and associated to the comics (Like Harry Potter maybe?). If this is wrong, then my question is due to my lack of knowledge.

In the series of The Punisher published on Netflix, in the first episode Frank deals with a belligerent drunk who was hitting on and insulting the female bartender. The bartender tells him her name is Beth and asks him to grab a drink at her place. (From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Punisher_(season_2)))

My question is pretty simple: Is Beth, the female bartender, a real character from the Marvel Comics?

Comment: MCU stuff tends to be much looser in its connection to the source material. I know some people complain about differences between the HP books and movies, but most of those are more stylistic than anything. In the MCU, they tend to stick to the basic outline of the comics (and then only to the extent that it's coherent - I'd be shocked if Carol Danvers story has half the significant elements in the movies as in the comics, and I think the comics just ret conned her origin to match the movie). Off the top of my head, I don't recall a significant Beth in Frank's past.

Comment: Marvel has a lot of "universes" the MCU is called "Earth-199999", the "main" universe is "Earth-616", I don't think Beth is a character in the comics so she could have been introduced in the MCU. Being an altercation of other Marvel universes it is bound to have a lot of similarities but it doesn't really follow the Earth-616 events or characters so strictly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Her full character name is [Beth Quinn](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5675620/characters/nm1111968?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t40). There are no recurring Marvel characters that go by that name. Her primary reason for existing was to show that Frank is finally ready to move on and start a new life. It also shows Frank that anybody who gets close to him gets hurt (so of course he relapses immediately).

I also can't find any evidence that her character is based off any short-lived character in the Punisher Series. Though I imagine there could be quite a few characters that match her description after 45 years of publications.